# How can I reduce the space between text and image on a button on android

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

[image]I have a button that has an image and a text below the image, I want to reduce the space between the two on android, on iOS there is no spaces in between, here is what I have done:

```
  <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button x:Name="btnApplyLeave"  ContentLayout="Top,0" BackgroundColor="White"  FontSize="10" TextColor="#777777"" ImageSource="applyleave.png" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor ="#ededed" Text="Apply Leave" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btnApplyLeave}}" >
                            <Button.CornerRadius>
                                <OnPlatform Android="6">

                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Button.CornerRadius>
                        </Button>

                        <Button x:Name="captureIntent" ContentLayout="Top,0" ImageSource="capturescores.png" Text="Capture Scores" TextColor="#777777 FontSize="10" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor ="#ededed" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference captureIntent}}" >
                            <Button.CornerRadius>
                                <OnPlatform Android="6">

                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Button.CornerRadius>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this issue is realted to the `ContentLayout` in the android platform.

[image]

If I set the value of  `spacing` to `-200` in the android Platform We can reduce the spacing.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            btnApplyLeave.ContentLayout = new Button.ButtonContentLayout(Button.ButtonContentLayout.ImagePosition.Top, -200);
        }
```

Comment: I tried doing the same in App.xaml but there's a bug when using that I suppose, this worked, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how to do it with a single button, but you could make a frame with a TapGestureRecognizer that will act like a button. 
The TapGestureRecognizer have both Tapped (like clicked on button) and Command for MVVM. The code needs some adjustment in your project, but you get the idea:

```
    <Frame HeightRequest="{Binding yourHeight}" CornerRadius="6" HasShadow="false" 
           BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#ededed" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <Image Source="image.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="TestText" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </Frame>
```

Comment: It worked but the button height slightly increased which makes it more rectangular rather than a square

Comment: Yes sorry, Frame has a default padding, so just set padding="0" on the frame.